# Will demons be thrown into the lake of fire or will they remain in the abyss forever?

Tags: demons, predestination

The book of Revelation shows us the identity of the first beings to be thrown into the lake of fire and these are the **false prophet, the beast, and the dragon**. These are thrown into the lake of fire first because they are already **judged**.

This action follows the **last battle** between **good and it's evil** called **Armageddon** where Satan gathers all nations of the world and **tries to attack** the **City of Saints** but **God who loves saints so dearly causes fire to come out of heaven and burns all these nations**. The devil is the **third** to be thrown into the lake of fire after the false prophet and the beast

Revelation 20:7-10

> <sup>**7**</sup> And when the thousand years are ended, Satan will be released from his prison <sup>**8**</sup> and will come out to deceive the nations that are at the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them for battle; their number is like the sand of the sea. <sup>**9**</sup> And they marched up over the broad plain of the earth and surrounded the camp of the saints and the beloved city, but fire came down from heaven and consumed them, <sup>**10**</sup> and the devil who had deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and sulfur where the beast and the false prophet were, and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever.

After **Satan is thrown into the lake of fire** God begins to raise the dead(I assume in this context the phrase dead refers to men) and judges all of them according to what's written in the **Book of Life**.

My question is, The devil fell with one-third of the angels in the beginning when he revolted in heaven against God. These angels are known to us as demons, is there any text that confirms to us whether they will remain in the **abyss** or **will be condemned to hell like their father the devil?**

This is because these demons appealed to Jesus when they had possessed a man and had said their name is **legion**, they begged Jesus not to send them into the **abyss** but instead send them to the **swine**. They also mention that Jesus may have come to torment them before their **appointed time**

Luke 8:30-33

> <sup>**30**</sup> Jesus then asked him, “What is your name?” And he said, “Legion,” for many demons had entered him. <sup>**31**</sup> And they begged him not to command them to depart into the abyss. <sup>**32**</sup> Now a large herd of pigs was feeding there on the hillside, and they begged him to let them enter these. So he gave them permission. <sup>**33**</sup> Then the demons came out of the man and entered the pigs, and the herd rushed down the steep bank into the lake and drowned.

Is the abyss the **eternal destiny of the angels who did not keep their former places and decided to join the devil in rebellion?**

This is because the Book of Revelation skips the judgment of demons and instead tells us about the judgment of the **unholy trinity** and of **men**, no mention of judgment of **fallen angels**

The judgment chain is also like this in order going down:

- The False Prophet
- The Beast
- The Dragon
- Men

I thought fallen angels would be judged after the dragon but the Book of Revelation fast forwards to men.